# Need to synchronize Windows Service with non-admin user process

Tags: .net, windows-services, ipc, mutex, privileges

I am using a (.NET2.0) service to periodically carry out privileged actions and return the result to shared memory, via IPC, with a non-admin user's (.NET2.0) process.

I have been using globally named mutexes while developing from my administrator account but when I come to try the application on a limited account I get the error:

> Additional information: Access to the path 'Global\timersyncu33sc3c2sd42frandomlynamedmutexoijfvgf9v3f32' is denied.

Is there some other way a non-privileged user can interact with a Service? Or should I just share the period of polling and update time and hope those values get written/read atomically?

Comment: Did you set ACLs on mutexes and shared memory you are using for IPC?

Comment: Seva Titov I have last week implemented such a solution and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following method of granting access to my limited users as they log on and fire up their GUI. Note the function `getUsername(/*somehow*/);` had several incarnations and I'm not listing the implementation that worked on XP, I'm sure there are other ways though 3 of the 4 I found didn't work for me.

```
void grantMutexToCurUser(Mutex ^%fpMutex) {
    try {
        fpMutex = Mutex::OpenExisting( ServerGUIBridge::NAMEDMUTEXFORTIMERSYNC,
            static_cast<MutexRights>(
            MutexRights::ReadPermissions | MutexRights::ChangePermissions) );

        MutexSecurity^ mSec = fpMutex->GetAccessControl();
        String^ user;

        try {
            user = getUsername(/*somehow*/);
            Trace::WriteLine( DateTime::Now.ToLongTimeString() + " - Granting mutex access to: " 
                + user , "grantMutexToCurUser" );
        } catch (Exception ^ex) {
            Trace::WriteLine( "getUsername: " + ex->Message, "grantMutexToCurUser" );
        }

        // First, the rule that denied the current user the right to enter and
        // release the mutex must be removed.
        MutexAccessRule^ rule = gcnew MutexAccessRule( user,
            static_cast<MutexRights>(MutexRights::Synchronize
            | MutexRights::Modify), AccessControlType::Deny );
        mSec->RemoveAccessRule( rule );

        // Now grant the user the correct rights.
        rule = gcnew MutexAccessRule( user,
            static_cast<MutexRights>(MutexRights::Synchronize
            | MutexRights::Modify), AccessControlType::Allow );
        mSec->AddAccessRule( rule );

        fpMutex->SetAccessControl( mSec );

        // Open the mutex with (MutexRights.Synchronize | MutexRights.Modify), the
        // rights required to enter and release the mutex.
        fpMutex = Mutex::OpenExisting( ewfmon::ServerGUIBridge::NAMEDMUTEXFORTIMERSYNC );
        //noThrowRelease(fpMutex);
    }
    catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException^ ex ) 
    {
        Trace::WriteLine( DateTime::Now.ToLongTimeString() + " - Unable to change permissions: "
            + ex->Message, "grantMutexToCurUser" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would talk to the service using WCF. This eliminates the privileges/identity problem.
However since your code is in .NET 2.0 you could use Remoting or NamedPipes to talk to the service.

Comment: No WCF in .NET 2.0. Ah, see you added NamedPipes. That racks up overhead as comms are on local machine. It's not the IPC that's the problem it's the ms sync'ing of reader and writer firing.

Comment: Good solution, see http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/04/12/getting-started-with-named-pipes.aspx for as simple example as could wish for, thanks to op elsewhere in StackOverflow.

Comment: Doh! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx#Y0 NamedPipes not available for .NET 2.0. Remoting is too much (is it even .NET?). Surely there's a better solution?

Comment: @John the class is not in .NET 2.0 but there are wrappers available that you can use. NamedPipe is a OS technology and is available to any language that can talk to win32 api. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart2.aspx

Comment: I've been looking at IPC Channels instead, as that is .NET 2+. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-ipc-channels-and-net-framework-20-to-communicate-between-processes/6143016 Seems I need to share an object between client and server which is impossible if one is an elevated service. __edit__ Just reached the end, "In Closing", "especially useful in the caseof Windows Services "

Comment: @John Your last bet is Sockets!